# Is it possible to recover a telegram contact using rawvalue saved on ipad?

Tags: telegram, contacts, recovery

I have deleted the chat and contact of someone in telegram. I don’t have his phone# or telegram ID. However, his contact has been saved in my ipad as a telegram address with rawvalue and it seems like https://t.me/@idId(rawValue:%2018935783201).
Is this contact recoverable or not? Is there any bot to convert rawvalue to real telegram account?
Thanks for your help.